# What is the probability that a random walk on this graphs ends at point A?

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Consider the symmetric RW on a graph constructed from two cycles $C_{m}$ and $C_{n}$ in such a way that the two cycles have exactly two consecutive common vertices, like in Figure 2.

[image]

Let S denote one of the two common vertices, let S' denote the other common vertex, let A be a vertex of $C_{m}$ not in $C_{n}$, and let B be a vertex of $C_{n}$ not in $C_{m}$. Suppose now that $m=2*10^{6}+1$, where the SS' A-arc is a path of $10^{6}+1$, edges and the other SA-arc(=“lower arc”) is a path of $10^{6}$ edges; and $n = 4*10^{6} +1$, where the SS'B-arc is a path of $2*10^{6} +1$ edges, and the other SB-arc(=“lower arc”) is a path of $2 * 10^{6}$ edges.

I am interested in the probability that the symmetric random walk, starting from S, ends at endpoint A. B is also an end point, however we are interested in solving the probability it ends at A. If the random walk reaches A at any time it immediately ends.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that the walk reaches A at some time in future?

Comment: Yes I am. If the walk reaches point A then it stops. If the walk reaches point B then it stops. I want to know the probability it stops at A

Comment: I don't think the question says it stops if it reaches B, does it?

Comment: I forgot to mention it because it wasn't of interest when solving for A. That is an important detail

Comment: It's a very important detail. You should edit it into the body of the question. No one should have to wade through the comments to learn what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the random walk also stops when reaching $B$, which the question currently doesn't say; otherwise, the probability is just $1$.

---

Divide the diagram into a top half (consisting of the $A,B$-path passing through $S'$) and a bottom half (consisting of the $A,B$-path passing through $S$).

By symmetry, the probability of reaching $A$ before $B$ is the same for a vertex in the top half and the corresponding vertex in the bottom half. So we can just solve the same problem for a random walk on a single $A,B$-path of length $3 \cdot 10^6$.

For this random walk, the probability of reaching $A$ before $B$, starting from $S$, is well-known to be $\frac{d(S,A)}{d(S,A) + d(S,B)}$ which gives $\frac13$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you I was confused at how to approach the problem and did not think about dividing the diagram in half. My intuition was it was 1/3 and I was simply thinking of using $\dfrac {m} {m+n}$